# How to use Assets.versioned api in controller layer in playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework

this maybe some strange. I want seperate all assets include html file to a fort-end dictionary rather then define scala.html file in package of app.view.

Hope this result when need a `index.html`:
1. define route in routes file
`GET /   controller.MyController.index`
2. define `index` method on MyController.scala

```
    def index = {
      Assets.versioned("/wwwroot", Assets.Asset("index.html"))
    }
```

actually, a normal way in play is return a `Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))` in `index` method.But I don't want put scala.html in view package because fortend has themselfs way to organizate these reources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need the controller, record in the `routes` is enough:

```
GET  /       controllers.Assets.at(path="/wwwroot", file="index.html")
```

Comment: How about do some authentication before return the Assets?Is it possible use `Assets.at` in a custom controller module?

Comment: You can use authentification filter and protect on the url pattern basis. You can also read the file inside controller, assets is just static files

Comment: I use pac4j for authentication, it has ready `SecurityFilter`. You can look as it implemented and repeat it (or use it): https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j#3b-protect-urls-via-the-securityfilter

Comment: Read static file: Inject `play.api.Environment` into the controller and read the file as `environment.getFile("/wwwroot/index.html")`.